# Game engine's tic delay in python - how to do?

Tags: python, game-engine

The GE has a simple feature that allows you to execute logic bricks at a given time (tics). For example, I can have my object move every 5 tics: Always (5 frequency) > and > Motion. How can I have tic delays of the GE in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more of a general programming question, than a Blender question, so you might have more luck over at StackOverflow, though they might also have trouble answering because you're in the Blender environment.

That being said, the general idea is that you want a check that will determine how much time has passed since the last "tic." You'll decide that a "tic" is 100 milliseconds, 10ms, 5ms; whatever length of time makes sense for your application (ticking too frequently is called "thrashing" the CPU, a term which might help you with future research). If enough time has passed, it executes a "tic." If not, it yields to some higher level process like an outer loop, the main program, or even the OS. You can yeild by having an `if` that just skips over some code if it's not time to tic yet, or you can use a function like `sleep()` that actually tells the CPU "I won't need any time on the processor for at least x seconds" and then the OS handles the wait time.

It's a common problem to which you should be able to find lots of solutions, some of which you'll be able to tailor to Blender.

More on sleep(): http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/

Hope that helps!

EDIT: With @blackhole 's contribution above, you know that a python script will run every tic. Knowing that, you can just skip tics:

```
tics_skipped = 0
if tics_skipped > 5
    #reset the counter
    tics_skipped = 0
    #then do the other things that need to happen here
else
    #otherwise, skip this tic and increment the counter
    tics_skipped = tics_skipped + 1
```

That being said, there's no guarantee that BGE tics are consistent. In fact, I'll bet you they aren't. A "tic" is probably a single pass of the GE doing everything that it needs to do for one frame. That might take 0.001 seconds, or it might take 10 seconds, but that's one tic. Depending on what you're trying to move and how, there's probably a good, standard way to do it. I just don't know what that is ;-)

You might use this same idea to check the amount of time that's passed, but you're going to have to look into how to get sub-second resolution. It's possible, but it's not trivial.

Comment: OK, thanks. As of know, I know little about python. If I use yield, would I do yield(x), x being the time? Also, I always thought a GE tick was equivalent to 1 ms anyways, is that right?

Comment: I really don't know about GE tics, I'm sure it's in the documentation somewhere. I'm sorry, it's not yield, it's sleep() and it's seconds, not ms. Sorry for the mistake ;-) You might could use `sleep()` and x would be the approximate number of seconds to wait until letting this process swap back on the CPU. The only thing about sleep() is I don't know how it will interact with the rest of the game engine. You'll have to do some experimentation to make sure it's not having any unintended consequences. Here's a bit more: http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/

Comment: Using sleep() makes my frametime @0.2 when its at sleep(1). The GE is faster when sleep() is lower (x-value). It seems that this isn't a timer.

Comment: No, that makes sense because it's not a timer at all. If "sleep(1)" says "I won't need to do any work for at least 1 second" then (apparently) it won't even draw a frame any more often than once a second (1.0 fps, probably less because it's doing more than just drawing a frame). Sleep(0.1) would let you draw a frame at most ten times a second. I was hoping sleep() wouldn't make the whole Engine sleep, but apparently that's what it's doing. The principle is still the same, though. I'll add a little pointer to the answer.

Comment: OK, thanks for update! I will check it out when I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

The always sensor not only triggers logic bricks but can run python scripts as well. Simply connect the sensor to a python controller and the chosen script will run every x ticks.

[image]

You can also alter the delay till the next script run by adjusting the `skippedTicks` property.

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
sens = cont.sensors['Always']
own = cont.owner

own.worldPosition.x += 5

if own.worldPosition.x % 10:
    sens.skippedTicks = 50
else:
    sens.skippedTicks = 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I wasn't clear, my bad on that. I was looking for a timer that runs on the same timer as GE tics. I'm not sure but 1 second = 60 tics. With this, I can use sleep() (as Matt stated below) but I'm not sure if 1 second = 60 tics, so I've asked for a timer that works with tics, not seconds/ms/etc.

Answer (score 0):

> The GE has a simple feature that allows you to execute logic bricks at a given time (tics). For example, I can have my object move every 5 tics: Always (5 frequency) > and > Motion. How can I have tic delays of the GE in python? Thanks.

You connect a Python controller with that sensor.

Every 5 frames the controller gets triggered and executed (regardless what controller it is).

You need to be careful when connecting other sensors. The controllers get executed when **any** sensor triggers them.

**Alternative**

You can get a much better control over the timing with a delay sensor. It will change from not positive to positive after a configured delay. This way you do not rely on trigger but an status. This is much robuster regarding side effects from other connected sensors.